# Running Fiware-Cygnus listener in CentOS

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have a VM with CentOS installed, where Orion Context Broker, Cygnus, Mosqquito and MongoDB are present. When I am checking connections with the following command:

```
netstat -ntlpd
```

I receive the following data [Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cau9R.png)

It is seen that something is already listening to ports 8081 and 5050 (which are of Cygnus). But the Cygnus itself is not active, when I use the following:

```
service cygnus status
```

> There aren't any instance of Cygnus running

While trying to run Cygnus test, it gives me fatal error which states that ports are taken and that the configuration is wrong.

Trying to run cygnus from

```
sudo service cygnus start
```

also fails. Here is the systemctl status: 
[FailedCygnus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTO3G.png)

After checking what is the process under the PID that is assigned to the Cygnus ports, I have this: 
[CygnusPorts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T6jg.png)

Perhaps someone has any clue what that can be? It feels like Cygnus is there but something is configured wrong. Also, is there another way of running Cygnus then, because I need to receive notifications from subscriptions somehow. 
Thank you in advance, Stackoverflow!

**EDIT 1**

Tried killing processes under those PIDs that are listening to ports 5050 and 8081 but it did not help, cygnus still cannot be started.
Currently thinking of simply reinstalling everything.

**EDIT 2**

So, I have managed to run the simple "dummy" listener using the agent_test file. But I guess it is good only in the beginning and for learning purposes, later using own configurations is preferred?

Comment: Run `ps -aux | grep "8081"` and `ps -aux | grep "5050"`. You will see what process are using ports 8081 and 5050. If you want, you can kill these processes and try to start Cygnus again.

Comment: @DaltonCézane  question edited

Answer (score 0):

So, for further investigation using agent-test.conf file is enough for me, the listener works and data is stored in a database. Perhaps in the future I will encounter this problem again, but for now it works.

What I had to do beforehand is to kill existing processes.

Comment: I think the issue is not a bug, but maybe when you stop the service, it is not stopped completely. As you state the solution is to find the process and kill it.

Comment: it perhaps is an error that may have happened during installation? Anyway, everything works now, and I am very happy :)

Comment: Thanks, for your feedback.